# In Azure Search, how do you run a "contains" search with multiple terms in searchtext?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-cognitive-search

I am using Azure Search in full query mode on top of CosmosDB and I want to run a query for any documents with a field that contains the string "azy do". This should match, for example, a document containing "lazy dog".

Reading the Azure Search documentation, it looks like this is impossible due to the term-based indexes it uses.

Rejected solutions

0 matches since it is looking for whole words:"azy do"

Doesn't work since regexes are not allowed to span multiple terms:/.*azy do.*/

This "works", to the extent that it will match "lazy dog", but this does not respect the ordering of the query and will also match "dog lazy", for example  /.*azy.*/ AND /.*do.*/

Is there any way of doing this correctly in Azure Search?

Comment: Can somebody help me creating a custom analyzer for the above mentioned use case?

Comment: Please tag Azure Search questions with [azure-search] in the future. Otherwise the Azure Search team isn't notified of your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot achieve that via regular expression in the Lucene Query syntax, then is not possible. You may want to vote for supporting contains [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/6470849-support-startswith-contains-and-endswith-wildcar).

Answer (score 0):

It should be /.*lazy|dog.*/
So, split the terms based on whitespaces and add a pipe(|) delimiter which stands for OR.

Answer (score 0):

Shortly, Azure Search is not designed to support this scenario. You might be better off using the [CONTAINS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sql-query-reference#bk_contains) function in Cosmos DB or its equivalent, depending on what query language you use.

Azure Search is designed for finding terms or phrases that occur in unstructured content (documents) and returning the most relevant documents. The process of extracting and indexing those searchable terms is customizable and described here: [How full text search works in Azure Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-lucene-query-architecture).